# SQLite Person Involved in A OR B

Tags: sqlite, join, left-join, outer-join

I'll be honest this is a homework question, but I've wasted hours into it and just can't get it right. It returns either the wrong number of results or the wrong data:

I need to select every person involved in directing a movie and/or acting in a movie and the amount of times they do, if it's at least 5 times.

There is an `acts` table with a `movie_id` and a `person_id`, `directs` with `movie_id` and `person_id` and `person` (`pid` and `name`).

What i've come up with is:

```
 SELECT p.name,count(d.mid)+count(a.mid) 
    FROM person p
    INNER JOIN  acts a
    ON a.pid=p.pid

    LEFT JOIN  directs d
    ON p.pid=d.pid

    group by p.pid,p.name

    having (count(d.mid) +count(a.mid))>=5
```

Basically, I'm trying to join the `person` and the `directs` table matching the `person_id` in both tables, while doing the same for `directs`. The problem is that the results from the second query aren't included (that Alfred Hitchcock with 10 movies has been bugging me from the start ).

I'm using sqlite, I'd be very happy if someone can give me a push in the right direction. I was instructed also to avoid aggregrated subqueries. I had a solution that used them but it took 15 minutes to execute.

Comment: i've tried it with UNION SELECT d.pid,d.mid from directs d since every director is also involved in either directing and/or acting. However, replace the second JOIN, i get an error no such colum a.mid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of this question, there is no relevant difference between actors and directors, both are involved persons.

So let's [create a view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) that hides the fact that involved persons are stored in two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW involved AS
SELECT mid, pid, 'actor'    AS role FROM acts
UNION ALL
SELECT mid, pid, 'director' AS role FROM directs
```

The question can then be solved with a simple join with `person`. (The `role` column isn't actually needed.)

---

Note: The question doesn't state what happens if some person is both actor and director for the same movie. If you leave out the `role` field and use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, this will be counted as only one involvement. But counting it as two makes more sense for me.

---

Another note: The database structure is badly designed for your question; the involvements should have been stored in a single table in the first place. But in real life, you do not always have the luxury of being able to change the database structure. (You might not be allowed to create even a view, in which case you'd have to use a temporary view, or write out the view as a subquery.)

Comment: thanks, I've rewritten it as a subquery and joined it on person, giving me the final result. What's more important is that I now actually know what was wrong and how it works/should work